# How to create a table from one JSON key,value pair

Tags: reactjs

I have a JSON object from my Flask backend which is *{'users': userValues, 'emotes': emoteValues}* where userValues is of the form

```
     userValues => [{'user': 'maiman', 'messages': 7}, {'user': '5HEB', 'messages': 7}, {'user': 'aploxus', 
     'messages': 7}, {'user': 'okizim', 'messages': 6}, {'user': 'new362', 'messages': 6}, {'user': 
     'normsbruhh', 'messages': 6}, {'user': 'afflot', 'messages': 6}, {'user': 'zipgunz', 'messages': 5}, 
     {'user': 'BiteLC', 'messages': 5}, {'user': 'Expyzap', 'messages': 5}]
```

and emoteValues is similar. I would like to create two separate tables, one for 'users' and another for 'emotes'. However when I try to create one, I get a *"TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"* when I try to do  data.users.map((item) in my return. I was wondering how I would correctly access just one (key, value) pair from the JSON object and then iterate over the value.

```
function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        fetch('/test')
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(data => setData(data))
    }, []);

    return (
        <div className="container">
            <h1>Table</h1>
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User</th>
                        <th># of Messages</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {
                        data.users.map((item) => (
                            <tr key={item.user}>
                                <td>{item.user}</td>
                                <td>{item.messages}</td>
                            </tr>
                        ))
                    }
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: Check for data.users being `undefined` - with `data.users && data.users.map`, or some other way. A chance is, you want to show something similar to 'Loading...' to your user anyway while waiting for the data to be loaded.

Comment: check for nulls / undefined when accessing objects that are set async. `data` does not exist on the first render, it exists on a re-render after the `fetch` is finished.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is, when your component renders the first time, the `fetch` call is issued and your `data` variable is currently `{}`. When you have an object and you try to access a key that does not exists, it does not raise an error, but returns undefined. So, trying to access `users` from `data` which is `{}` returns `undefined`. When you try to `map` through `undefined`, you get the error because `map` is a function to be run on arrays.

You can render a spinner to show that you are fetching the data from the API or just render the blank table while no data is available.

So, in order to avoid getting the error, you can either check `data.users` before trying to map it or just add `?` in between values that can be undefined.

The easiest and cleanest way is to switch `data.users.map()` to `data.users?.map()`, since `data` is not undefined, but an empty object.